# Have a 2 click counters and am wanting to save the overall total based on the day of the week

Tags: javascript

I have a Codepen https://codepen.io/Jonbeckner/pen/KKewOQq that I am working on. I have 2 click counters that displays an overall total in a box below the click counters. I have placed a button within, that I'd like to have save the total to the corresponding day of the week. I know how to add an event listener for the button but beyond that I am still learning JS.

My ask is this: when

```
<button class=" button button-save">
                    Save Total
                </button>
```

is clicked save the overall total

```
<p>Total Units =&nbsp;
            <span id="total-units">
                0
            </span>
```

to the corresponding day of the week. The total for Monday would display under M Tuesday under T and so forth.

I grabbed the current click counter from Codepen and have added to and modified it to my need thus far. I am still learning JS so please excuse my beginner knowledge.

Comment: I searched your question for a sentence that ends with a question mark and didn't find one.  Can you be more direct and specific in your questioning, please?  "beyond that I'm still learning" is not a direct way to phrase a question.  and "I'd like to have save the total..." is not a clear enough description of the problem you are facing.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't very clear. I am asking for methods of saving the total units to my site. I know an event listener is needed for the save button but what direction do I take beyond that?

Comment: I think you're asking:  "How can I make element X display 'Y' when I click button Z"? Is that all?  Is that the specific part you're stuck on?

Comment: To answer your question, yes. I can figure out the if statement for the days.

Comment: What do you mean by "save data to my site".  Do you mean to the backend, e.g. a webserver and database? Or do you mean to local storage in the browser?  Or do you just mean update the text of some element on your page?

Comment: I am not sure which is better. I would like guidance on what path to take. the total number is what i'm hoping to save to the corresponding day element. but what method is best for me to research. This will be used on a w3schools website.

Comment: I'll provide an answer the first part, but if you don't know what you want for the second part and don't have specific requirements then you're in danger of soliciting opinions if you're just "asking for guidance" without a specific description of what "save data to my site" means to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no framework, just plain HTML+JS, you can change text of an element in response to a button click like this, by setting its `innerText`.

```js
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('total-units').innerText = '42';
});
```

```html
<button id="save" class=" button button-save">Save Total</button>
<p>Total Units = <span id="total-units">0</span></p>
```

#### Saving data

As for saving data, you have three major choices:

1. **In the DOM**.  Just update text of an element and it'll stay that way until you change it or refresh the page in your browser.  This is not permanent at all and won't survive closing the browser or a power outage.  This is only saved in-memory in the browser while you're looking at the page, and is basically like *not saving the data at all*.
2. **In [local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)**.  Data saved in local storage will survive a page refresh and will be there the next time you visit the page.  But if you visit from another browser or from another computer, the data won't be there.
3. **In the backend**.  The webserver that serves your web app in the first place can also provide a REST API to receive the data and can persist it in a database component in the backend and serve it back to you when needed.  Your saved data is just as available as the page itself and is persisted "in the backend" in a database.  This is the most work, but it's the way most of the internet works.

Comment: That will help me get to where I want to be. Thank you.

Comment: I added notes about saving data.  local storage may be good enough for you, but please, next time have some well-defined requirements before asking.

Comment: I have this bit of code 
'document.getElementById("button-save").addEventListener("click", function () {
document.getElementById('suntotal').innerText = "";
});'
How do I set innerText to the total units? resultNode is my total so I think.